# Deploying a contract on private Ethereum network Harmony

Tags: private-blockchain, ethereumj, java, harmony

I just started on ethereum and I created  a private ethereum network on harmony and we were able to syn up to other peers using the same router .

Question would like to ask is how do u deploy the contract on a private network in harmony?

Been searching around on how to do it but am not too sure.

Answer (score 2):

Will leave answer for history.

For now, contract deployment in private Harmony is possible using next tools:

- using truffle and pointing to Harmony JSON-RPC at http://localhost:8080
- using Ethereum Studio and running Harmony binded to public IP with HTTPS. Need to confirm untrusted certificate before operating. Steps are kind of quest :-).
- any other tools, which works with JSON-RPC enabled nodes.